# how to env odoo model with serach conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, orm, odoo, odoo-12

i'am made a model it called part number as examble it contains the part number as name field and car and model fields,
also in product.template view i'am added thos tow fields car and model and a button with method
to print the part number which contins the same self car and model 
it's works well but it givs no result if i remove search conditions it print all results 
this the code

```
class autopart(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'

@api.multi
@api.depends('car','model')
def partnum(self):
    part=self.env['part_num'].search([('model_id', '=', 'model'),('car_id', '=', 'car')])
    print(part)
    pass

car = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="cars", store=True, string="Car", ondelete='restrict', required=False, )
model = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="models", store=True, string="Model", ondelete='restrict', required=False,default='', domain="[('car','=', car )]")
```

and this is the part num model

```
class part_num(models.Model):
_rec_name = 'name'
_name = 'part_num'

name = fields.Char(string="name",required=True)

car_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="cars", string="car", required=False, )
model_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="models", string="model", required=False, )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Fouad try this way it may work

```
part=self.env['part_num'].search([('model_id', '=', self.model.id),('car_id', '=', self.car.id)])
```

as your using 'car' odoo consider it as a name and not an object